# Change the download chunk size in pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

Building a youtube video downloader using `pytube`. I want to change the chunk size and make it smaller (by default it is 9 MB).

```py
from pytube import YouTube
def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining): #I want this to be called more often
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
    percentage_of_completion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
    print(percentage_of_completion)


def main(url):
    yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
    video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    print(video.filesize)
    video.download()
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know there is a function or like a something to do it...
looking at the pytube library you can find a file named
"request.py"

```
"""Implements a simple wrapper around urlopen."""
import http.client
import json
import logging
import re
import socket
from functools import lru_cache
from urllib import parse
from urllib.error import URLError
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

from pytube.exceptions import RegexMatchError, MaxRetriesExceeded
from pytube.helpers import regex_search

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
default_range_size = 9437184  # 9MB**
```

you can change 'default_range_size' variable value to change chunk size

**default_range_size = 1 * 1024 * 1024**     #----> **1MB**